# Retrieve parameter in AjaxStart event

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I get parameter information of Jquery ajax request in ajaxStart event?

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'myurl.com',
          type: 'Post',
          data: {
              myajax: 'This is my ajax.'
          },
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          }
       });

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    //Can I get "myajax" parameter here?
});
```

Thanks all.

Comment: i dont think you can, you could check for ajaxSend though

Comment: Thanks. I can catch it in ajax send event.